Using Fourier Series Features in XGBoost
I have a question about feature engineering. I'm using XGBoost for forecasting, and someone suggested adding Fourier features to capture seasonality and improve model performance. I believe it just creates a more complex model and won't help much. Additionally, I don't fully understand how to use Fourier series and harmonics. Can you explain this?
Explain Fourier Series Feautures

This is not a question about programming, so doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. There are dedicated communities in the SE network for machine learning, try [stats.se] or [datascience.se]. Please read their help center to learn what is on-topic in each. -- To learn about Fourier series, please do a Google search, there are millions of lectures, tutorials, blog posts, etc. about the topic.
